# CSS Flexbox: Aligning Children of Flex Items

Tags: css, flexbox, alignment, text-alignment

I am using Flexbox with `flex-wrap` so that when the `flex-items` are equal width, the items will be wrapped so to make the layout responsive.

I would like to achieve that the Name, Email and Phone will be horizontally aligned.

[image]

Note: Although I may make the `phone` into another `div` and apply `justify between`, however that doesn't make email to align (in case the name is too long).  Do we have ways to keep the grid while preserving the wrap?

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.employee {
  flex: 1;
  width: 20em;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9g41t4g8/

```js
$( () => {
 fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10&nat=us&inc=name,picture,email,phone&seed=abc")
   .then( r => r.json() )
    .then(
     j => {
       j.results.map( (e, i) => {
         $("#employee").clone(true)
          .appendTo($("#container"))
            .attr( 'id', "employee_"+i )
            .find("img").attr( "src", e.picture.thumbnail ).end()
            .find(".name").text( e.name.first + " " + e.name.last ).end()
            .find(".email").text( e.email.repeat(i) ).end()
            .find(".phone").text( e.phone ).end()
            .show()
        })
       
      }
    )
})
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.employee {
  flex: 1;
  width: 20em;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

#employee {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="employee" id="employee">
    <img/>
    <div class="name">
      Name
    </div>
    <div class="email">
      Email
    </div>
    <div class="phone">
      Phone
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Try to set min-height for email,phone,title as follow.

Comment: Sorry I don't get what it means by "follow".  As a side note, say for the employee name, it can range from 1 line to 3 lines, if I set `min-height` to 3 lines, then there will be rows with 1-line names and then 2 blank lines which does not look fit...

Comment: Yes,without any black space how to make it all email,phone in same row.

Comment: Please refer to here: https://jsfiddle.net/7gvscLy0/
So if `min-height` for name is 3-line then there may be too many extra blank lines.  While `table` can achieve my goal, it is not responsive (it will not make 3 data per row into 2). I wonder if this can be achieved.

Comment: Is display: grid an option ?

Comment: Yes, even with JavaScript is acceptable.  With a little bit more research I've found that this may eventually need something like subgrid to get it done... https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2017/07/20/why-display-contents-is-not-css-grid-layout-subgrid/

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned your code a bit. Introduced `flex-basis` and `min-width` to `.employee` to retain the employee size to match across different screen sizes. `.employee` becomes

```
.employee {
  min-width: 0%;
  flex-basis:30%;
  height:auto;
  border:1px solid;
  flex-direction: column;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Firstly, the data is not same across the employees. Some employees doesn't have phone data, but have couple of emails. cleaning the data will have the expected output across screen sizes.

If you have to live with non cleaned data and wanted to maintain the details in same line? Introduce `flex: 1` to the updated `.employee` class. But the employee boxes will look distorted

```
.employee {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 0%;
  flex-basis:30%;
  height:auto;
  border:1px solid;
  flex-direction: column;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7qgnjj00/5/

Comment: Thanks. Using Chrome, I see it vertically aligned, however for the 2nd row (jayden ferguson, rhonda henry, terra moore) there phone number (details) are not on the same line.. I need horizontal alignment and vertical is only a plus. Any ideas?

Comment: It is happening because of the email content. For the mentioned names emails content varies. One way to achieve on the same line can be achieved by having a horizontal scroll bar for email.